# How do I set an MSpec test as inconclusive?

Tags: c#, mspec

How do I set an MSpec test as inconclusive in the test? 
I am looking for an equivalent of [Nunit Assert.Inconclusive](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.5)

I'm using version 0.9.3.0.

Comment: Hello!!! Is anyone still using Mspec?

Answer (score 2):

While there is no inconclusive state in mspec, what you could do is to skip the implementation of the `It` delegate. This will make the specification "Not implemented".

```
It should_be_inconclusive;
```

Another option might be to ignore the context or a specific `It` using `IgnoreAttribute`.

```
[Ignore("This test is currently inconclusive")]
It should_not_be_null = () => Subject.ShouldNotBeNull();
```

https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications#usage

Answer (score -1):

Just tested throwing an exception in the constructor of the class annotated with Subject seems to do the trick.

I have a popup so not ideal..